# Dependency Injection and Constructor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a class called `Template`. Inside it I create a new instance of the class `ClasseDiProva`.

Inside `ClasseDiProva` I `@Autowire` a class called `I18nMessageHandler`. When I call `ClasseDiProva.stampaMessaggio()`, where I call a method of `I18nMessageHandler`, I get a `RunTimeException`, but I can't s understand why.

Everything works if, inside the class`Template`, I `@autowire` `ClasseDiProva` instead of doing `ClasseDiProva classeDiProva  = new ClasseDiProva()`.

I suppose is a Dependency Injection issue.

The problem is that I need to do `ClasseDiProva classeDiProva  = new ClasseDiProva(voce)` since `ClasseDiProva` has many constructors and I have to use a specific constructor that has as a paramether an object `Voce`, that is a object that I know only inside `Template.getPageTitle`.

```
@Component
public class Template {   
        public String getPageTitle(Voce voce){
            ClasseDiProva classeDiProva = new ClasseDiProva(voce);
            classeDiProva.stampaMessaggio();               
        }
}
```

```
@Component
public class ClasseDiProva {
        private Voce voce;

        @Autowired
        private I18nMessageHandler i18nMessageHandler;  

        public ClasseDiProva() {            
        }   

        public ClasseDiProva(Voce voce) {
          this.voce = voce;               
        }

        public void stampaMessaggio(){  
           System.out.println(i18nMessageHandler.getMessage(this.voce.getTitle, null, "defaultMessage"));
        }
}
```

```
@Component
//@Configurable
public class I18nMessageHandler {
    @Autowired
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
    @Autowired
    private LogHandler logHandler;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(I18nMessageHandler.class);    

    public I18nMessageHandler() {
    }

    public String getMessage(String codiceStringa, Object[] args, String defaultMessage) {
        try {       
            return messageSource.getMessage(codiceStringa, args, defaultMessage, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            logHandler.writeLog(logger, LogHandler.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            return defaultMessage;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: When you get an Exception, you need to _always_ provide the exception + stacktrace

Comment: Spring will only inject dependencies into object instances it controls. You are creating new ones yourself and those will not be injected. Use the bean factory to obtain an instance for you or inject/add the needed dependencies yourself.

Comment: It seems to be empy. I saw with the degubber that I get a RunTimeException. The problem seems to be that i18nMessageHandler inside ClasseDiProva is null. The @Autowired is not working